# Sysnative on Vista RTM

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, architecture

I am currently writing a batch script that will start processes on an operating system. This batch script is called from a test application that is built and run as a 32-bit application on both 32-bit and 64-bit operating systems. The batch script is written as follows:

```
set EXE=%1
if exist %WINDIR%\sysnative\%1 ( set EXE=%WINDIR%\sysnative\%1 )
start "" "%EXE%"
```

I am using the sysnative variable to start up 64-bit applications on 64-bit operating systems and 32-bit applications on 32-bit operating systems. I use this script on operating systems of Vista and beyond. It works properly on all operating systems except Windows Vista x64 RTM. When called, I receive a "The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log for more detail."

I have opened a 32-bit command line on Windows Vista x64 RTM and navigated to C:\Windows\sysnative and attempted to call notepad.exe, calc.exe, etc. from there and always receive the same error. I've also tried uninstall and reinstalling the Microsoft Visual c++ 2008 Redistributable Packages but to no avail. The Application/Security/System event logs do not contain any information/warning/error messages pertaining to this. This issue is only encountered on Windows Vista x64 RTM. Any thoughts?

Comment: The SysNative variable _is_ available in Vista 64-bit, so it sounds more like your Vista's WinSXS is corrupted.  Does it do this on every Vista machine, or just the one you tested? Have you tried it on a fresh Vista install yet?

Comment: It only occurs on this Vista machine. The scripts works on Vista x86/x64 SP1 & SP2 and Vista x86 RTM. It only occurred on this specific machine. I will try creating a new Vista install and seeing if I experience the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You miss a C++ Runtime. Run the Command prompt (cmd.exe) with [admin rights](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token) and run this command:

```
SxsTrace Trace -logfile:SxsTrace.etl
```

Now run the script which causes the SideBySide error.

Go back to the command prompt press ENTER/RETURN to generate the SxsTrace.etl. Now type this:

```
sxstrace Parse -logfile:SxSTrace.etl -outfile:SxSTrace.txt
```

Now open the SxSTrace.txt trace and look which VC++ runtime is missing.

If you are unsure, please upload the complete SxSTrace.txt to a cloud service/pastebin and post a link here.

Comment: I ran the steps as described above and am unsure as to which VC++ is missing given the output. The results are posted at [link](http://pastebin.com/GaE4zE5P)

Comment: ok, looks like no Runtime is missing. I can't really see anything useful from it. Maybe this is a Bug which was fixed with the Sp1.

Answer (score -1):

> It only occurs on this Vista machine.

The SysNative variable is available in Vista 64-bit, so it sounds more like your Vista's WinSxS is corrupted.

The easiest fix for a messed up WinSxS is to just reinstall the OS from scratch.

An alternative is to forcefully take ownership of WinSxS and it's files, and then copy the files from a known-good Vista 64-bit machine, then change the ownership back, and perform an `SFC /scannow`.

More detail on performing those actions wound be outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: I created a new reinstall of the Vista x64 OS RTM and experienced the same issue when attempting to perform the same steps as above. I've run the sxstrace as suggested by @magicandre1981 and posted the results on pastebin (see comment on his suggestion).